# ACK for 802.11 broadcast frame?

Tags: wifi

On 802.11 if I send a unicast frame, receiver will acknowledge by sending an ACK frame. But what about a broadcast frame? For example, A want to send a broadcast frame. A sends it to AP, AP acknowledges. Then AP broadcasts the frame. Does the AP listen for ACKs?

What about 802.3 Ethernet? Does Ethernet broadcasts ask for ACKs?

Thanks!

Comment: Ethernet doesn't ack anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the AP will not listen for acks when it broadcasts your (broadcast) frame. And no, 802.3 Ethernet does not ack broadcasts either.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your answer earlier.

Answer (score 0):

No. For broadcast data/frame AP won't expect and listen acks. In 802.3 Ethernet also it doesn't give ack for broadcast frame